large Memory usage when running backward pass for a DiT
I'm having hard time understanding memory allocation during backward pass of a LLM. As I increase the depth of the LLM, Im seeing huge increment in the backward pass as compared to what estimated using https://www.latent.space/p/transformers-math
I'm running on a single GPU for now, but have the FSDP(FULL shard) enabled though. which I use to scale the model. Im using pytorch lightning to run the model



Depth
mem before DiT blocks
mem after DiT blocks
mem after backward




2
6081
8445
27527


10
13201
16525
64533


20
22101
26865
OOM



I've tried to see if its just cache or something, but running torch.cuda.empty_cache() doesn't really make the numbers very different as well, eventually the model ends up allocating the same memory, to run efficiently I believe.
